# How large must the sample be?

Tags: probability, statistics

Could anyone explain how to go about solving this question?

> In a certain population, 15% carry a certain gene believed to be responsible for a disease. A sample will be chosen from the population for a study. How large must the sample be if we want to be 90% sure that the sample will contain at least one person carrying this gene?

Comment: Hint: What is the probability that $n$ chosen people don't have the desease? For $n = 1$ it's $85%$, for $n = 2$ it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming independence, the probability that none of the sample of $n$ have the gene is $0.85^n$.

Thus we need $n$ big enough that this value is ...